# How to move to end of temporary buffer in emacs inside function

Tags: emacs, elisp, buffer

I am trying to write an emacs function that will run `make` in the current directory, change to another directory and run `make link` all while outputting the text to a new buffer called **make-output** (original, eh?). Once complete, I'd like to move to the *end* of the **make-output** buffer so that I can see whether the compile was successful. Here is what I've got currently:

```
(defun remake-libefp-interface()
  "Will run make in the current directory, change to the NWChem src directory and relink the binary."
  (interactive)
  (defvar T_pwd (getenv "PWD"))
  (defvar T_top (concat (getenv "NWCHEM_TOP") "/src"))
  (defvar cmd (concat "make; cd " T_top "; make link;cd " T_pwd))
  (with-output-to-temp-buffer "*make-output*"
    (shell-command cmd "*make-output*")
    (pop-to-buffer "*make-output*")
    (end-of-buffer)))
```

This recompiles correctly, but dumps me at the *beginninng* of **make-output**. I have also tried replacing the `(end-of-buffer)` with `(goto-char (point-max))`, but this also left me at the beginning.

Comment: Would `(compile (concat "make; cd " T_top "; make link;cd " T_pwd))` do what you want?

Comment: Yes. This, in conjunction with `(setq compliation-scroll-output t)` does a better job of what I'm trying to accomplish since it's color coded. Thanks for the tip. I'm marking Drew's response as the answer since it technically answers the question I asked, but your response was more helpful for getting to what I wanted.

Comment: In a program, don't use command (end-of-buffer), which may slow down it. Use (goto-char (point-max))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `pop-to-buffer` and `(goto-char (point-max))` outside the `with-output-to-temp-buffer`.